# How do I replace values on a dataframe of positions by a list of columns and rows?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Let's say I have a dataframe called `df` and I want to replace the values of the columns number 1,4,6 and the rows 3,5,8,9 by the number 0

I want to replace values that are both in the columns and in the rows, so 3x4=12 values in total

I tried

```
df[3,5,8,9][1,4,6]=0
```

but it doesn't work

Comment: Notice that Python indexing starts at 0. So, if by column number n, you mean the nth column of the data, its index would be n-1

Answer (score 2):

Use `iloc`:

```
df.iloc[[3,5,8,9],[1,4,6]] = 0
```

Comment: @CinfaCinfa Just be aware that python indexing starts with 0.

Answer (score 1):

if i understood you well, you can try this code that uses `.loc` indexer to replace the values in the specified rows and columns with the number `0` in the  df :

```
 import pandas as pd
    
    # Sample DataFrame
    data = {'A': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10],
            'B': [11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20],
            'C': [21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30],
            'D': [31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40],
            'E': [41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 50],
            'F': [51, 52, 53, 54, 55, 56, 57, 58, 59, 60]}
    
    df = pd.DataFrame(data)
    
    # Rows and columns to replace
    rows_to_replace = [3, 5, 8, 9]
    cols_to_replace = [1, 4, 6]
    
    # Replace values using .loc indexer
    df.loc[rows_to_replace, cols_to_replace] = 0
    
    print(df)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
import pandas as pd

data = [[1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8],
        [2, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17],
        [3, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27],
        [4, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37],
        [5, 40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47],
        [6, 50, 51, 52, 53, 54, 55, 56, 57],
        [7, 60, 61, 62, 63, 64, 65, 66, 67],
        [8, 70, 71, 72, 73, 74, 75, 76, 77],
        [9, 80, 81, 82, 83, 84, 85, 86, 87]]

df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['id', 'col1', 'col2', 'col3', 'col4', 'col5', 'col6', 'col7', 'col8'])


for col in ['col3', 'col5', 'col8']:
    df.loc[[1,4,6], col] = 0
    
print(df)

id  col1  col2  col3  col4  col5  col6  col7  col8
0   1     1     2     3     4     5     6     7     8
1   2    10    11     0    13     0    15    16     0
2   3    20    21    22    23    24    25    26    27
3   4    30    31    32    33    34    35    36    37
4   5    40    41     0    43     0    45    46     0
5   6    50    51    52    53    54    55    56    57
6   7    60    61     0    63     0    65    66     0
7   8    70    71    72    73    74    75    76    77
8   9    80    81    82    83    84    85    86    87
```